# PCA in R - trying to compute Normalize scores instead of normalize loadings

Tags: r, normalization, pca, scaling, eviews

I am trying to calculate normalize scores of my PC instead of normalize loadings. I have tried to use princomp and prcomp package. All my data are scaled and centered.

In Eviews there is just one click by default:
the loadings are normalized so the observation scores have norms proportional to the eigenvalues (Normalize loadings). You may instead choose to normalize the scores instead of the loadings (Normalize scores) so that the observation score norms are proportional to unity.

In the other forum I found that: "
Normalize loadings - means that your scores will have variances equal to the estimated eigenvalues
Normalize scores - means that your scores will have unit variances

The latter corresponds to whether you want the eigenvalue decomposition computed using the covariance or the correlation matrix of the data."
I did that, and the result was still not similar to eviews normalized score.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your exact question here? I can't seem to find it in your post. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.